# au dehors (de) vs en dehors (de) vs par dehors (de)

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

D'après [le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/dehors) :

> au dehors (loc. adv.) + de = À l'extérieur + de
>   en dehors + de = à/vers l'extérieur + de
>   par dehors = par l'extérieur.

Et voici [un Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=au+dehors%2C+en+dehors%2C+par+dehors&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cau%20dehors%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cen%20dehors%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpar%20dehors%3B%2Cc0).

Prière de faire ressortir les points communs et les divergences ? Les trois me paraissent analogues.

En outre, je n'aperçois pas « par dehors de » dans les ressources fournies par le CNRTL. Y a-t-il une raison à cette absence ?

Comment: It should be noted that another meaning or use of 'en dehors de' is 'apart from.'

Answer (score 1):

- Arriver *de dehors* (de l'extérieur) dans un lieu clos
- Il arrive *par-dehors* dans le salon (il est sorti à l'extérieur de la
  cuisine et est rentré ensuite dans le salon, alors qu'il aurait pu se
  déplacer à l'intérieur de la maison)
- La maison était douillette au dedans mais d'allure austère *au dehors* (point de vue d'une personne qui n'est pas *[au] dedans*)
- *En dehors* de la maison, aucune âme qui vive dans cet enclos (Exclusion de ce qui n'est pas 'dedans')